# Passing struct literal to ObjC method

Tags: objective-c, struct

During [a talk at the @Scale 2014 conference](http://youtu.be/XhXC4SKOGfQ) (around 32:30), Facebook presented their implementation of a declarative UI approach. The slides for a more detailed version of the talk can be found [here](https://qconsf.com/system/files/presentation-slides/components.pdf).

Basically they presented a function call like this (I made my own simplified example from the example in the talk):

```
[CPInsetComponent
  newWithStyle:{
    .margin = 15
  }
];
```

My question is: Is this valid ObjC code? I tried to implement this myself

```
typedef struct {
  uint margin;
} CPInsetComponentStyle;


@interface CPInsetComponent : NSObject

+ (SomeOtherStruct) newWithStyle:(CPInsetComponentStyle)style;

@end
```

but I still get an "expected expression" error  on the `newWithStyle:{` line. Could you give me a hint how the method declaration would look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not valid Objective-C code. A C99 compound literal of struct type looks like this:

```
(TheStructType) { .field1 = initializer1, .field2 = initializer2 }
```

where the field designators are optional.

I can imagine that the code they were presenting was actually Objective-C++. In C++11, the compiler can insert implicit calls to constructors taking an initializer list if certain conditions are met; hence, often you can pass just an initializer list to a function.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler probably doesn't know if your literal struct declaration is of the correct type. For compound literals you need to provide the type in parenthesis followed by a brace-enclosed list of initializers.

```
[CPInsetComponent newWithStyle:(CPInsetComponentStyle){
  .margin = 15
}];
```

Comment: That's not a typecast – it's just that compound literals happen to have the same syntax as casting.

Comment: Seems like a pedantic reading of the spec that doesn't effect the outcome. Any other source describes it as an anonymous object whose type is specified by the cast.